# EWS sends invitations to everyone when removing a required attendee

Tags: c#, vb.net, exchangewebservices

I have the following code:

(Meeting beeing the exchange appointment)

```
For Each Recipient As String In emailAdresses 
    For i As Integer = 0 To Meeting.RequiredAttendees.Count - 1
        If (Meeting.RequiredAttendees(i).Address).ToUpper() = Recipient.ToUpper() Then
            Meeting.RequiredAttendees.RemoveAt(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next

Meeting.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendOnlyToChanged)
```

Now as you can see i'm using SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendOnlyToChanged.

But even though that i'm using that mode it is still sending the appointment to all of the attendees.

I've looked at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633620%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) and the code is exactly the same. And msdn tells me the following should happen:

> Save the meeting and send a meeting cancellation message to the attendee or attendees that you removed

So basically msdn sais it is works but it does not. Is there a work around for this issue or is anyone else experiencing the same problem?

our exchange server is a 2007 SP1 version.

The answer can be in C# or VB.NET, I'll translate it to the language we need.

PS. Adding members and using this mode causes the invite to send to the newly added member only. But as I said before deleting does not have this same behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing:

```
Meeting.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.NeverOverwrite, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendOnlyToChanged)
```

Instead of:

```
Meeting.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendOnlyToChanged)
```

Solved my problem, I do not know why and what it was having trouble with though.

Comment: That didn't resolve the problem for us, we're using Exchange 2010 ... still sending mail to all recipients on removal ...

Answer (score 1):

Using `ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve` instead of `ConflictResolutionMode.NeverOverwrite` did not work for me. After some research, I found out that this is the normal behaviour.

The [`SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.sendinvitationsorcancellationsmode%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) enum's values `SendOnlyToChanged` and `SendToChangedAndSaveCopy` behave similarly when it comes to sending email (the only difference is that the latter saves a copy of the sent email and the former doesn't):

> Send meeting invitations/cancellations only to attendees that have
>   been added or modified

There is no reference to attendees that have been removed. I thought that the work 'modified' here means that, but apparently that is not the case.

This [Microsoft Support Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2873493) (Article ID: 2873493) says that this is the expected behaviour:

> **EWS issue: SentToChangeAndSaveCopy parameter in Appointment.Update
>   method does not work**
>
> **Symptoms**
>
> > Consider the following scenario:
> >
> > - You build an Exchange Web Services (EWS) application to update a meeting request in a Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 environment.
> > - One or more invitees in the meeting request are externals or distribution lists.
> > - You use the **Appointment.Update** method together with the **SentToChangeAndSaveCopy** parameter to remove one invitee from the
> >       meeting request and to update the meeting request.
> >
> > In this scenario, **a meeting update is sent to all invitees**.
>
> **Cause**
>
> > **This behavior is expected.**