# EWS API: Remove attendee and set "SendOnlyToChanged" sends update to everyone

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I try to remove an attendee programmatically from an appointment and update it with the option `SendOnlyToChanged`. The problem is all attendees also receiving an email with an update about the meeting, and not only the changed.

```
appointmentOutlook.update( ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite,SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendOnlyToChanged );
```

I found the same question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/e8690d70-bc1d-40a4-98c5-d3cf9512fadb/problem-with-sendonlytochanged) on exchange server forum, but also without success.

Did anybody found a solution or workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use `ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve`.

Don't ask me why it works this way, it was in an [answer to a *more recent* question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672603/ews-sends-invitations-to-everyone-when-removing-a-required-attendee) then yours.

(So I won't mark either answer as duplicate, but just refer to it).

Comment: That didn't resolve the problem for us, we're using Exchange 2010 ... still sending mail to all recipients on removal ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is example with API from Independentsoft. Administrator sends meeting request to Mark, John and Peter and decided to remove John from meeting.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date startTime = dateFormat.parse("2013-01-03 18:00:00");
Date endTime = dateFormat.parse("2013-01-03 19:00:00");

Appointment appointment = new Appointment();
appointment.setSubject("Test15");
appointment.setBody(new Body("Body text."));
appointment.setStartTime(startTime);
appointment.setEndTime(endTime);
appointment.setLocation("Room 123");
appointment.setReminderIsSet(true);
appointment.setReminderMinutesBeforeStart(30);
appointment.getRequiredAttendees().add(new Attendee("Mark@mydomain3.com"));          
appointment.getRequiredAttendees().add(new Attendee("John@mydomain3.com"));
appointment.getRequiredAttendees().add(new Attendee("Peter@mydomain3.com"));

ItemId itemId = service.sendMeetingRequest(appointment);

//add first
ItemChange itemChange1 = new ItemChange(itemId);
itemChange1.getPropertiesToSet().add(new Property(AppointmentPropertyPath.REQUIRED_ATTENDEES, new Attendee("Mark@mydomain3.com")));

itemId = service.updateItem(itemChange1, SendMeetingOption.SEND_TO_CHANGED_AND_SAVE_COPY);

{ //add others non-removed in a loop

    ItemChange itemChange2 = new ItemChange(itemId);
    itemChange2.getPropertiesToAppend().add(new Property(AppointmentPropertyPath.REQUIRED_ATTENDEES, new Attendee("Peter@mydomain3.com")));

    itemId = service.updateItem(itemChange2, SendMeetingOption.SEND_TO_CHANGED_AND_SAVE_COPY);
}
```